# Autoscroll div issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make a div scroll as content is added into it. I am using a Vuejs list which updates items as source array (a vuejs's data array) changes.

```
<message v-for="message in messages"></message>
```

This is my auto-scroll pseudo-code:

```
let scroll = false;

messagesContainer.addMessageChild(new messageElement(...)); // addMessageChild appends item to vuejs's data, it may be async when it actually adds the element to the DOM which may cause the problem

if (messagesContainer.scrollTop = maxScrollOfMessagesContainer)
    scroll = true;
messagesContainer.scrollTop = maxScrollOfMessagesContainer;
```

However, the messages container element does not scroll. I fear that Vuejs may update (insert) elements from source (data) asynchronously, this way possibly skipping the `if (messagesContainer.scrollTop = maxScrollOfMessagesContainer)` check (Adding the element (message) after the check).

What could I possibly do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

What about a method to scroll on the last message ?

**Template:**

```
<message v-for="message in messages" v-class="last-message : $index === (items.length-1)">
</message >
```

**Methods:**

```
// smooth scroll on .last-message
scrollToLastMessage: function () {
  document.querySelector('.last-message').scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth' 
  })
}

// scroll when messages change
watch: {
  messages: function () {
    this.scrollToLastMessage()
  }
}

// scroll when page ready
ready() {
  this.scrollToLastMessage()
}
```